# Where to find the Yosemite traffic light icons?

Tags: macos, themes

Where would I be able to acquire Yosemite's new "traffic light" icons? I have found the `SystemAppearance.car` file, but I do not know how to decompress `.car` files, or if the file even contains the icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.car file is special BOM file and the file specification is un-document by apple, this is simulator with Assert.car in iOS.

I found an open source project [ThemeEngine](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine)
PS: I don't test it anymore.

Comment: Is there any compiled version of ThemeEngine? I just see a bunch of source code.

Comment: include release App on GitHub https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine/releases